# Applying Dijkstra algorithm on a SQLite database

Tags: python, database, sqlite, graph, dijkstra

I am currently working on a project where I am using a database to store the connections between Wikipedia pages as a graph. I am trying to use Dijkstra's algorithm or another algorithm to find the shortest path between two pages using these connections. However, I am not sure how to properly implement this algorithm using my current database structure.

My database has two tables, one for nodes (representing the Wikipedia pages) and one for edges (representing the connections between the pages). Each edge has a start node and an end node, which are connected to the corresponding nodes in the nodes table.

I have been researching how to use Dijkstra's algorithm in this context, but I am still not clear on how to properly use it with my specific database setup. Can anyone help me understand how to properly implement this algorithm with my current setup?[This is the structure of Nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDNEJ.png) [This is the structure of Relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIJEl.png)

Making a database with all the pages and their respective hyperlinks is a lot of data, and I assume that to apply the algorithm I need to load the database in memory, but I doubt that I can do this since there will be a huge amount of data with their relations

Comment: consider using https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html, then the only thing you have to figure out is how to initiate your graph with the database in hand, then dijkstra is just a class function

Comment: I don't know if having in memory a network with a massive amount of data for each query I have to do is the best idea, isn't it? @Dr.Prof.Patrick

Comment: Do not need to copy everything into memory - just the adjacency data and the index of each node.  Spin up a graph theory library ( networkx for example ), populate it from your database, then apply the Dijkstra library method..

Comment: Although the question mentions SQLite, finding shortest path would be much faster on Graph Databases.
You can try Apache AGE (PostgreSQL extension with graph db functionality) to find the shortest path between two Wikipedia pages. It can handle large amounts of data and their relations effectively. [Here's](https://dev.to/matheusfarias03/exploring-shortest-path-algorithms-with-apache-age-oap) an article on using Apache AGE for finding the shortest path